# How to display selected checkboxes on another page using javascript bring to another page in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox

I would like to display selected checkboxes from another page into form page? I create a form pages in `form.aspx` and description pages `desc.aspx`.
How to make when user select checkboxes in `desc.aspx` it  will display the selected checkboxes in the table at `form.aspx` using javascript? For instance when user checks on `desc.aspx` page it will directed transfer the checks data into table in `form.aspx` page

Code table in `form.aspx`

```
<table id="course">
  <tr>
     <td> No </td>
     <td> Course Code </td>
     <td> Subject </td>
     <td> Student Id </td>
     <td> Marks </td>
     <td> Class </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
     <th> <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox13" runat="server"/></th> 
     <th> 
          <asp:DropDownList ID="select" runat="server" CssClass="form-pd" onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
              <asp:ListItem value="">21456</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem value="https://localhost:44386/desc"> More....</asp:ListItem>
           </asp:DropDownList> 
     </th> 
     <th> </th>
     <th> </th>
     <th> </th>
     <th> </th>      
 </tr>

</table>
```

Code in `desc.aspx`

```
 <tr>
                    <th> <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"/> </th>
                    <th> MT413 </th>
                    <th> Calculus </th>
                    <th> <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="form-input" required="required"></th>
                    <th> <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="form-input" required="required"> </th>
                    <th> 2-A </th>                  
                </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <th> <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server"/> </th>
                    <th> MT413 </th>
                    <th> Calculus </th>
                    <th> <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="form-input" required="required"></th>
                    <th> <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="form-input" required="required"></th>
                    <th> 2-A </th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th> <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server"/></th>
                    <th> MT413 </th>
                    <th> Calculus </th>
                    <th> <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="form-input" required="required"> </th>
                    <th> <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="form-input" required="required"> </th>
                    <th> 2-A </th>                  
                </tr>
```

Comment: You can't modify another page. You must navagate to that other page. I mean, if you come to my web site, and I can change or look at your OTHER pages open? Then I would look for some open "banking" or "credit card" page open. Or if you are shopping on Amazon, I'll take over that page and do some shopping for you! Now, perhaps you mean the user selects some options on one page, and then say hits a button to navigate to another page (and pass selected values? Sure, that is common. However ability to change or modify values in one open web page to another is not allowed and a security risk.

Comment: I've searched for another solutions, but found only slightly similar ones https://www.tutorialspoint.com/display-selected-checkboxes-on-another-page-using-javascript not exactly what I need but similar to source from this link @Albert D.Kallal

Comment: But you link in the comments ASSUMES that the user will hit submit and NAVAGATE to the next page. And that is quite much my quesiton here. That link you suggest DOES NOT modify values in the other page. It only SAVES values in the current page, AND THEN opens + navigates to the new page (and passing values along for the ride in local storage). that example in NO WAY shows how to update another page from the existing page one is on. No question one could say use a "timer" of some sorts, and have both pages consume the same session data. (but that link does no such thing).

Comment: so yes, if that one user opens both pages (and you not explained how that is occurring), you could poll say the database or even session, and that would work. It not clear how that 2nd page was or will be opened.  So, you can't modify another page, but if both pages are designed with this idea in mind, it can be done.

Comment: User need to fill up the form in form.aspx pages. In the same page they have description table when user click on the dropdown list in the table it will popup to the new pages which is desc.aspx. Then when user checks or tick the checkboxes in desc.aspx pages,  the data will transfer to the table in form pages.  Means that user will have 2 pages opened. That's how it will work but currently right now i'm still figure on how checkboxes would transfer data based on user selection

Comment: ah, ok, so then user does some selecting, and then navigates to a another page - great! - I can help and post some ideas.  this is a common idea then, and "vast" different then updating some other page already open.  Let me post something in a bit then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first up, I would have to assume this data for table is not "hard coded", but comes from a data source.

However, right below your table, you have a button, say like this:

```
        <asp:Button ID="cmdDone" runat="server" Text="Continue"
            CssClass="btn"
            OnClick="cmdDone_Click"
            />
```

And so when you click this button, we gather/get the choices, save into session, and then navigate to the next page.

Say this code:

```
Protected Sub cmdDone_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' build list of choices

    Dim MyChoices As New List(Of String)

    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        MyChoices.Add("Calculus")
    End If

    If CheckBox2.Checked Then
        MyChoices.Add("Math of Finance<")
    End If

    If CheckBox3.Checked Then
        MyChoices.Add("Algorithms")
    End If

    Session("Choices") = MyChoices

    ' now navigate to 2nd page
    Response.Redirect("MyForm.aspx")

End Sub
```

(also, don't call the web page "form.aspx", as "form" is a reserved word).

So, now in the 2nd page (MyForm.aspx in this example).

Then we could have this markup:

```
        <h3>Courses Selected from Prevous page</h3>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Width="216px">

        </asp:ListBox>
```

and code behind this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim MyChoices As List(Of String)
        MyChoices = Session("Choices")

        For Each sChoice As String In MyChoices
            ListBox1.Items.Add(sChoice)
        Next

    End If
End Sub
```

And the result is this:

[image]

so the concept, the idea, the proof of concept above?

It shows how we can gather/get choices from one page, and pass to the next.

However, a real solution would of course not have the data "hard coded" as per htis example.

Normally, a gridview or table would be filled out from the database.

We then loop the rows, (test for each row if it has a check box).
We build up that list of choices (database PK id).

Then use session() to pass that list of "id" values picked based on checkbox.

Then navigate to the next page, get list of choices from session, and then display the results - again this should come from a database, and we would in practice use the "id list", and re-pull the data from the database to display the courses chosen by the user.

So, now the effect would be this: